# Titlesec + Tikz: consistent underlining

Tags: tikz-pgf, sectioning, formatting, titlesec

I'm trying to create a custom section style using titlesec and Tikz. My current code is the following:

```
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\definecolor{mygreen}{RGB}{25,170,75}

\titleformat{\section}[display]{\bfseries \color{mygreen} \huge} {}{0pt}
  {
         \thesection \hspace{0.5cm} #1 \\
         \begin{tikzpicture}
         \draw[fill=mygreen, mygreen, rounded corners, xshift=-2cm](0.1\paperwidth, 0cm) rectangle (0.9\paperwidth, 0.1cm);
         \end{tikzpicture}
}
```

Note that the what tikz is doing is a simple rectangle whose function is to underline the text. I had to include the line break (`\\`) between the text and Tikz to ensure a good positioning. I have two problems:

1. I would like to control the start of the line from the left marging of the page -but now it is aligning to left-bottom of the text. For now I have a `xshift=-2cm`, but this is not a good solution since I am using a two-sided document, and the margin is different in odd and even pages.
2. I cannot control the vertical space between the line and the text. I tried to remove the line break and use some `vspace`, but the result is not very good looking.

I'm aware of the `current page` node in Tikz, but that seems to give always absolute positions, and I do not know where the coordinates of the section are. I have been digging in forums and the manuals for some hours and I cannot figure out a solution. Is there any way of controlling the position of my underline?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `tikzpagenodes` and `tikzmark`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\definecolor{mygreen}{RGB}{25,170,75}

\titleformat{\section}[display]{\bfseries\color{mygreen}\huge}{}{0pt}
  {\thesection \hspace{0.5cm} #1\tikzmark{s-\number\value{section}}
         \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
          \path (pic cs:s-\number\value{section}) coordinate (tmp);
          \draw[fill=mygreen, mygreen, rounded corners=1pt]
           ([yshift=-1ex]tmp-|current page text area.west)  rectangle
           ([yshift=-1ex-1mm]tmp-|current page text area.east);
         \end{tikzpicture}
}[\vspace{2mm}]
\begin{document}
\section{A section}
Blah blub

\section{Another section}

Blah blub pft

\clearpage
\section{Yet another section}

Blah blub pft

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It looks like `tikzpagenodes` is a very useful package for my purpose -and it even supports the two-sided docuements.  
However, I do not understand why I need the `tikzmark` and its related code. Is it not enough to use the `current page text area` to locate the text?

Comment: @VictorSeven We get the horizontal positions from `tikzpagenodes`. Now we need to fix the vertical position (since this is an overlay picture). No, you do not necessarily need `tikzmark` but it is a very well tested library which allows is to do what we need to do.